# What happens when a circuit is grounded, and how to calculate a circuit's potential differences, current, etc. when it's grounded?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground

What would be the voltages of points A, B, C & D? How do I calculate them? What's happening here?

[image]

Comment: Hi! This is a very very basic excercise, so it's not very clear where to start explaining - it might be better to start reviewing your own learning materials instead of hoping for us to tell you the same.

Comment: We don't give out solutions to questions that look like homework problems. We will expect you to show that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself. Show all of your work, then ask a specific question. In this case, I suggest you start with KVL and Ohm's Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that no current is flowing in our out of that ground.  In this case, ground is just the reference point against which you measure the voltages. Set that node to zero, then you can work out the voltages at all other nodes relative to this one.

Comment: If no current is flowing out, how is the circuit complete? I mean how is current getting back to the battery?
Im sorry I might ask stupid questions. I have a hard time grasping physics concepts.

Comment: Via the three resistors.  Don't think of the ground as a path to or from anywhere...it is just the point in the circuit we are calling "zero volts".  Therefore, voltage will be "negative" at node D, and "positive" on A and B.  All things are relative.

Comment: @DVA The "complete circuit" is the battery and the three resistors. The ground symbol at node C is simply a statement that we chose node C to be at 0 V. Because all the voltage drops are *relative* voltages, this lets you conclude the absolute voltages at nodes A/B/D.

Comment: what will be the voltage at D?

Comment: @DVA We don't hand out answers to homework here. Do some work to try to solve this yourself, then come back if you have a specific question.